# Maximum of $ab+2bc+3ca$ with $a^4+b^4+c^4=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb R^+$ with $a^4+b^4+c^4=1$. What is the maximal value $ab+2bc+3ca$ can take?
I tried using Cauchy-Schwarz several different ways and the best upper bound I got was $\sqrt{14}$, but it was never sharp.
Numerical search suggests that the maximum occurs at about $a=0.763316$, $b=0.697312$, $c=0.80698$ with $ab+2bc+3ca=3.505647$, though I couldn't find any valuable relation between these numbers and the rationals.

Comment: I also tried on [*Wolfram Alpha*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum++a+b%2B2+b+c%2B3+c+a+subject+to+a%5E4%2Bb%5E4%2Bc%5E4%3D1), but it basically validates your results (there appears to be a symmetry).

Comment: But Wolfram gives nothing useful for a closed form for $3.505647.$ Things like $$\sqrt{14+\pi-7\log 2}.$$

Comment: @Moo Yes, if you negate a, b and c, neither the fourth powers nor the products change. That's why I specified $a,b,c \in \mathbb R^+$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Even though it does not find a closed form, you can do things like [*Wolfram Alpha*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3.50564702819083064485870176865224342803) to get closed form expressions.

Comment: Well, $b+3c=\lambda a^3, a + 2c=\lambda b^3, 2b+3a=\lambda c^3$ with $\lambda=2ab+6ac+4bc$. Would someone try to find the minimal polynomial for the answer? ;)

Comment: @Moo Yeah, the output above was what I got from WA when I did that. It seems unlikely the closed forms I got were the right ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough to look for non-negative variables.

Let $f(a,b,c)=ab+2bc+3ac+\lambda(a^4+b^4+c^4-1)$ and $a=xb$.

Thus, in the critical point we have
$$b+2c+4\lambda a^3=a+2c+4\lambda b^3=2b+3a+4\lambda c^3=0,$$ which gives
$$\frac{b+3c}{a^3}=\frac{a+2c}{b^3}=\frac{2b+3a}{c^3}.$$ 
From the first equation we obtain:
$$c=\frac{a^4-b^4}{3b^3-2a^3},$$ which after substitution in the second gives
$$\frac{(x^4-1)^3}{(3-2x^3)^3}\left(x+\frac{2(x^4-1)}{3-2x^3}\right)=2+3x$$ or
$$45x^{13}+34x^{12}-288x^{10}-183x^9-6x^8+648x^7+432x^6-9x^5-642x^4-432x^3+246x+160=0,$$
which gives $x=1.09465...$ or $x=1.26369...$ and we can show that $x=1.09465...$ gives a maximal value.